# Is the usage of "number" in "the number of greenhouse gases" correct?

Tags: word-usage

The following sentence is from CNN. Is the "number" properly used?

> Net zero is a scenario where the number of greenhouse gases emitted are no greater than the amount removed from the atmosphere, largely through a method known as carbon capture.

Answer (score 3):

It's unfortunate that we get a sentence like that from a serious journalistic source. No, there are multiple problems.

- *Can we talk about number of gases?* Sure, but that's not what this sentence is doing. "Number of gases" could be appropriate in "The number of gases in Earth's atmosphere is greater than that of Venus's" (no idea whether that's true). We're counting *types* of gas, not amounts. The second half of the CNN sentence clearly talks about "amount," so "number" was a bad choice.
- Technically, there's a disagreement in number between a noun and verb here: *... a scenario where the **number** of gases **are** no greater than...*. The noun that goes with the verb "are" is not "gases" but "number," which is singular. (This is a rule so frequently broken that it might be too picky to make a big deal about it, but it adds to the awkwardness of the sentence.

What would be a good rewrite?

> Net zero is a scenario in which the amount of greenhouse gases emitted is no greater than the amount removed from the atmosphere, largely through a method known as carbon capture.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is incorrect because "gas" is an uncountable noun (like "flour", "water", etc.). The correct word in this context should have been **"amount"** or **"concentration"**. The number telling how many different gaseous chemical substances supposed to be of "greenhouse" variety are in the air does not make sense, because it is the concentrations and types of the gases, not the number of types of the gases that matter in this context. For example, let's suppose the concentrations and types would be:

- carbon dioxide at 400 ppm;
- water vapor at 1000 ppm;
- nitrous oxide at 0.3 ppm;

...

- methane at 1.8 ppm.

The number of gases would be just a single number, like "16". Decreasing the concentrations would give a lot of specific data to present, for example that "methane concentration decreased from 1.8 to 1.0 ppm". Talking about "number of gases" suggests something like "the number of greenhouse gases decreased from 16 to 12", which would be absolutely useless, suspicious, or even actively deceitful if the concentrations of the remaining 12 greenhouse gases were to increase substantially creating a net-increase of heat retention in atmosphere.

PS Articles like that, in newspapers like that, are usually written by freelance ghostwriters for hire, who most often have no idea what they are talking about. All the specific information they get is the general topic to write about, maybe a list of buzzwords provided by some marketing weasel to check out and pepper into the article, and about half an hour of googling to become an "expert" in the domain they haven't ever heard about. I used to work like that for a certain online newspaper, and I was also writing block-headed articles like that, for 0.08$ per word.